# What is the best way to partition the $4$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, set-partition, extremal-combinatorics

*Also asked on MO: [What is the best way to partition the $4$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363026/).*

Consider the set $X = \{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. Define the collection of all $4$-subsets of $X$ by $$\mathcal A=\{Y\subset X: Y\text{ contains exactly $4$ elements}.\}$$

I want to partition $\mathcal A$ into groups $A_1,A_2,\dots, A_m\subset \mathcal A$ (each of them is a collection of $4$-subsets of $X$) such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i=\mathcal A$ and such that the intersection of any two distinct $4$-subsets in each $A_k$ has cardinality at most $1$, i.e. such that for all $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $Y_1, Y_2\in A_i$, we have $$Y_1\neq Y_2 \implies \lvert Y_1\cap Y_2\rvert \le 1.$$

**My question:** What can be said about the smallest $m$ (depending on $n$) such that such a partition exists?

---

**My thoughts:** I was expecting that each $A_i$ can contain "roughly" $\frac n4$ elements, so we would have $$m(n)=\Theta\left(\frac{\binom n4}{\frac n4}\right)=\Theta(n^3).$$ In particular, we would have $m(n)\le c n^3$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb R$.

However, I am neither sure if this is correct, nor how to formalize this.

Comment: If considering a $4$-subset as a vertex of the graph where edge between any two vertices exists when the subsets intersection has a cardinaliny $>1$ then we have to build a minimal [antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain) cover in other words, is that so?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, don't we want the chromatic number of this graph?

Comment: I asked [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363198/clique-cover-number-of-a-generalized-kneser-graph-kn-4-2) related question at MathOverflow.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Seems there is more machinery behind that question than I thought :)

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps, here are values for small $n$: $$m(4)=1, m(5)=5, m(6)=15, m(7)=18, m(8)=35, m(9)=42.$$
For all $n$, we have $m(n)\le\binom{n}{4}$ (trivially) and $m(n)\le m(n-1)+\binom{n-1}{3}$ by extending an optimal coloring for $n-1$ with one in which each 4-subset that contains $n$ gets its own color.

The independence number $\alpha(n)$ is the size of a largest independent set and provides a lower bound on the chromatic number: $m(n) \ge \lceil\binom{n}{4}/\alpha(n)\rceil$.  At least for $n \le 9$, this lower bound is tight.  The values of $\alpha(n)$ are [OEIS A004037](https://oeis.org/A004037).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find anything on OEIS though. Also, both your estimates seem to lead to $O(n^4)$. I think this is not sharp. Out of curiosity: How did you determine $m(n)$ ?

Comment: I solved the graph coloring problem using integer linear programming.

Comment: Please add this sequence to the OEIS.

Comment: For $n=4$, there is only one possible $4$-subset. In this case, no "intersection between distinct subsets" is possible. Thus, shouldn't we have $m(4)=0$?

Comment: @Anatoly, every partition must contain at least one part.  In terms of graph coloring, every node uses a color, so you need at least one color.

Comment: Surely this is the case in the graph approach. Are we sure that the possibility of partitions with one single element is allowed in the OP?  The statement about "distinct" subsets may be confusing.

Comment: @Anatoly, the condition $\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i=\mathcal A$ requires $m \ge 1$ when $\mathcal A$ is not empty.  The "any two distinct" condition is vacuously true if a part contains only one 4-subset.

Comment: I agree that such interpretation is the most adequate. Maybe it could be useful to reword the OP to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, I meant what RobPratt said and my „formal part“ of the formulation should correspond to that. Of course it could still be confusing so feel free to edit.

Comment: A counterpart of a conjecture $m(n)=\lceil\binom{n}{4}/\alpha(n)\rceil$ holds if we replace the condition $|Y_1\cap Y_2|\le 1$ by $|Y_1\cap Y_2|=0$, see this [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363101/independent-sets-in-complement-of-kneser-graphs) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363198/clique-cover-number-of-a-generalized-kneser-graph-kn-4-2) question for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**Proposition 1**.  If $n$ is a power of an odd prime then $m(n)\le n^2$.

*Proof*. It is well-known (see, for instance, [Lan]) that there exists a field $F$ of order $n$. For each elements $x,y$ of $F$ let $A(x,y)$ consists of all four-element subsets $\{a,b,c,d\}$ of $F$ such that $a+b+c+d=x$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=y$. We claim that for each $x,y\in F$ and each distinct $Y_1, Y_2\in A(x,y)$ we have $|Y_1\cap Y_2|=1$. Suppose to the contrary that
$Y_1=\{a,b,c_1,d_1\}$ and $Y_2=\{a,b,c_2,d_2\}$. Then $c_1+d_1=c_2+d_2$ and $c_1^2+d_1^2=c_2^2+d_2^2$. That is
$c_1-c_2=d_2-d_1$ and $c_1^2- c_2^2=d_2^2-d_1^2$. Since $c_1=c_2$ iff $d_1=d_2$ iff $\{a,b,c_1,d_1\}=\{a,b,c_2,d_2\}$, we see that $e=c_1-c_2=d_2-d_1$ and so   $c_1+c_2=d_2+d_1$. This follows $2c_1=2d_2$, so $c_1=d_2$ and $d_1=c_2$, a contradiction. $\square$

**Proposition 2**.  For sufficiently large $n$, $m(n)\le (n+n^{0.525})^2$.

*Proof*. It follows from Proposition 1, because for sufficiently large $x$ there is a prime belonging to $[x-x^{0.525}, x]$, see [BHP]. $\square$.

*References*

[BHP] R. Baker, G. Harman, J. Pintz, *[The difference between consecutive primes. II](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.360.3671&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*.
Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., (3) Ser. 83 (2001) 532–562.

[Lan] Serge Lang, *Algebra*, Addison-Wesley, Reading, Mass., 1965 (Russian translation, Moskow, 1968)

Comment: Thanks for the cool method! Make sure to also check out this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/363104/159578

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such **upper bound** since you can take this partition $A_i =\{Y_i\}$ for each four element $Y_i$ in $X$, so $$m= {n\choose 4}$$

On the other hand we have **lower bound**:

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1,A_2,....A_m\}$ and we seek for $m$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a set of all pairs in $X$. For fixed $A_i$ make a bipartite graph $ G=(A_i,\mathcal{P})$ where $Y_l\in A_i$ is connected to pair $P_j$ iff $P_j\subset Y_l$. Clearly the degree of each $Y_l$ is ${4\choose 2}=6$ and the degree of each pair $P_j$ is at most $1$ (since no pair can appear in two sets from $A_i$). So we have $$|A_i|\cdot 6 \leq {n\choose 2} \implies \boxed{|A_i|\leq {n(n-1)\over 12}}$$

Now $${n\choose 4}= \sum _{i=1}^m |A_i| \leq m {n(n-1)\over 12}$$ so $$\boxed{m\geq {(n-2)(n-3)\over 2}}$$